# read from file and split on various delimiters and store in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am trying to create a python program that splits on various symbols such as ; or ,  I have a text file like this:

```
bobby b ;   1999/3/3
danny d , 1994/7/7
```

Notice the spacing too. I want to split on various symbols I have tried using this:

```
d={}
f = open('names.txt', "r")
for line in f:
    test= re.split(r'\s*[;,.]\s*', line)
    firstName=test[0]
    dateName=test[1] # 

    print firstName, dateName
```

The names seem to be ok, when I print firstname[0] I get the name e.g. danny d but when I try date[1] I get an out of range error. why is this?

Comment: When I use exactly that file, and run that code with no changes other than fixing your `IndentationError`, `date` is `'1999/3/3'` and `'1994/7/7'` in each line, respectively, and `date[1]` is therefore `'9'` both times, never an "out of range error" (which isn't actually the name of any Python exception). Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): code we can run that demonstrates the problem, and the actual traceback, not just a vague description of it.

Comment: Is the new indentation actually correct? Because you're only printing once, after the loop is finished; you just set `firstName` and `date` over and over, doing absolutely nothing with all but the ones that come from the very last line, and then printing out the last ones. Of course that won't cause your error, but it doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: I get this exact message:                                          `code`     File "./test.py", line 13, in <module>
           dateName=test[1]
             IndexError: list index out of range `

Comment: There is no line that says `dateName=test[1]` in the code you've shown us. So, again, you're asking us to debug a program that we can't see, by looking at a different program that doesn't have the same bug. Please read the link in my first comment and give us a verifiable example.

Comment: at the moment I am trying to overcome the error. But yes the last print will be inside the for loop to.

Comment: @abarnert Now I have edited correctly and apologies for causing confusion.  But I still get the error.

Comment: You still haven't edited correctly. Your question still doesn't show the exception. It still refers to "when I try date[1]", which doesn't happen anywhere in your code. And, most importantly, it still doesn't reproduce the error. See [this repl.it session](http://repl.it/3s9). (I've embedded the data into the code instead of storing it as a separate file, but it's obviously doing the same thing.) It successfully prints out the exact two lines of output you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way the code and data you've shown us can produce the problem you've described.

However, I'm willing to bet your actual data produce a *similar* problem.

Consider what happens if you have a blank line in the data:

```
>>> line = ''
>>> test = re.split(r'\s*[;,.]\s*', line)
>>> test
['']
>>> date=test[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, you don't even get to the `date[1]` code that you're complaining about (but haven't shown us).

Comment: Yes the indentation was a slip up. Fixed. When print out test I clearly see that there is a value in the position [1] so I dont understand how I get the out of range error.

Comment: @user1766709: Again, stop describing the situation vaguely and give us an actual, debuggable example if you want us to debug your code/data.

Comment: I just deleted the text file and made a new one and it works fine. That wasnt a vague description thats all I had. I dont understand how it wouldnt work. but anyway thanks.

Comment: @user1766709: Nobody can show you the exact problem anymore because you haven't shown us the data and no longer have it, but clearly, in the original text file you had, there was a line that didn't have a `;`, `,` or `.` (whether because it was blank, or otherwise), and your code doesn't handle such lines, as shown by the example above.

Answer (score 0):

As abarnert says in his answer  the error is because of when *you have a blank line in the data* !

also i suggest if the format of all lines are like `bobby b ;   1999/3/3` that first name is in leading and date in trailing you dont need `regex` just `split` the lines and pick first entry and last !

```
>>> s="bobby b ;   1999/3/3"
>>> s.split()
['bobby', 'b', ';', '1999/3/3']
>>> s.split()[0]
'bobby'
>>> s.split()[-1]
'1999/3/3'
```

So for refuse of same error use an `if`  condition :

```
with open('names.txt', "r") as f :
 for line in f.readlines():
    if len(line):
      print "name is : " + line.split()[0] 
      print "name is : " + line.split()[-1]
```

Comment: I think you're solving the wrong problem. Despite the misleading variable name `firstName`, he says he wants the whole name ("e.g. danny d"), and what he's complaining about is that he gets an error trying to access`date[1]`, not that he's unhappy with `name`.

Comment: @abarnert yep , thanks , now i read your answer , you point to a good point ! get my +1 !

Comment: I'd like some feedback from the OP before I'm too confident in my answer, or any other. Until then, yours is still a reasonable guess. Maybe not one I'd bet on with huge odds, but definitely reasonable.

Comment: @yes you are right ! i think its better to wait for a complete feedback from the OP before write any answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip()` to delete spaces.

```
d="""bobby b ;   1999/3/3
danny d , 1994/7/7"""

import re
for line in d.splitlines():
    test= re.split(';|,',line)
    firstName=test[0].strip().split(" ")[1]
    date=test[1].strip()
    print firstName, date
```

Output:

```
b 1999/3/3
d 1994/7/7
```

If you wanna get the whole name, you don't need to split to get first/last name. You need also to map your variable name<==> date, where names are unique, and you can get the date by using the name as a key to get this information.

```
import re
D={}
for line in d.splitlines():
    test= re.split(';|,',line)
    firstName=test[0].strip()
    date=test[1].strip()
    D[firstName]=date
print D
```

Output:

```
{'danny d': '1994/7/7', 'bobby b': '1999/3/3'}
```

You need to store name/date in dictionary, so you can get the date directly by choosing the name.

```
print D['danny d'] #Output: '1994/7/7'
```

In case you wanna store dates in a list, and get them by accessing to this list through an index. You can define date/first name as a list. and store variable everytime you go through the file

```
import re
D={}
firstName,date=[],[]
for line in d.splitlines():
    test= re.split(';|,',line)
    firstName+=[test[0].strip()]
    date+=[test[1].strip()]

print date[1] #1994/7/7
```

Your list date should have this content `['1999/3/3', '1994/7/7']`

Comment: How does this solve the problem? His existing code produces the exact same output, except that he's printing the entire name, rather than the last initial. (Also, why would the last initial be a better match for a variable called `firstName` than the entire name is?)

Comment: OK, your new version now produces _exactly_ the same output as the OP's original code, so again, how does that solve his problem?

Comment: It's better to map the name/dates in dictionary, so he can access to those info by calling **D['danny d']** to get date related to this person. He's trying to get **date[1]** where date is a temporary variable where he stocks dates that he reads while traversing the file, he's not storing dates variables, but he's trying to derive info. ANother suggestion would be to store those variable in list **date** like: **date+=[test[0]]** so he could get name by **date[1]**

Comment: Telling him how to do what he already says he's going to do _after_ solving the problem doesn't help him solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

this is what you want: you need to use [Escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)

```
>>> l='danny d , 1994/7/7'
>>> re.split('[;,\.//]',l)
['danny d ', ' 1994', '7', '7']


>>> l='danny d , 1994/7/7'
>>> name,date = re.split('[;,\.]',l)
>>> name
'danny d '
>>> date
' 1994/7/7'
```

you can use `strip` to remove unwanted space from begining  and end

Comment: No. A `.` inside a character class means a literal `'.'` character, and using a raw string literal means you don't need to escape backslashes in the expression.

Comment: apologies I want to keep the date all as one. I am placing it in a dictionary so will match the name with the d.o.b. Can you see anything alarming about the one I had used? especially the out of range problem.

Comment: @abarnert >>> re.split('[\.]',k)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> re.split('[.]',k)
['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: @Hackaholic: Yes, of course both raw string literals and regular string literals with backslash escapes both work. And, for that matter, unnecessary backslashes inside a character class also work. So what? Your changes still don't fix anything, and your explanation of why they fix it (which they don't do) is still wrong.

Comment: @abarnert i am not wrong, see this and verify urself >>> re.split('[\b]',k)
['a.b.c']
>>> re.split('[b]',k)
['a.', '.c']

Comment: @Hackaholic: The backslash before `.` in your answer does nothing at all. Try `re.split('[;,.]', 'a.b.c')` and `re.split('[;,\.]', 'a.b.c.')`; they produce the same result. The fact that adding an unnecessary backslash in this different example actually _causes a new problem_ doesn't mean anything except that (a) because you're still, unlike the OP, not using raw string literals, that `\b` is a backslash character, and (b) if you fixed that, `\b` is a regex character class, unlike `\.`.